# How remove duplicate values from the result of a generator function

Tags: javascript

**I have three generators function the third one is delegate function**

```
function* genNumbers() {
    yield* [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  }

  function* genLetters() {
    yield* ["A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D"];
  }

  function* genAll() {
    yield* genNumbers();
    yield* genLetters();
  }

  let generator = genAll();
```

I want to print the all values by using the `generator.next()` But **Remove **the duplicate value, like that:

```
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: 1, done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: 2, done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: 3, done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: 4, done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: 5, done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: "A", done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: "B", done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: "C", done: false}
  console.log(generator.next()); // {value: "D", done: false}
```

Comment: `* genAll` needs to make use of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and two new [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)s. The latter for generating unique values and the former for creating the correct array to yield from. e.g. `function* genAll() { yield* [ ...new Set([...genNumbers()]), ...new Set([...genLetters()]) ]; }`

Comment: @PeterSeliger  You could certainly spread, but might be worth pointing out on large datasets this would me less memory efficient.

Comment: @Keith ... you're right, one certainly has to take this as an issue into account. (btw. did not take back the -1 cause didn't vote in first place)

Comment: @Nicolas SO is similarly not a "fix a bug for me" service. "How to" questions are not only allowed but expected and some of the most highly viewed and voted for. Not every question requires an attempt because not every question is about fixing a bug in existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping things generator based, you could just create a generator that takes your returned generator that does the de-duping.  Doing this you could then keep this as a util you can use in other places.

Generators that take generators as source is a very memory efficient way of processing huge amounts of data, as it avoid intermediate memory storage.

```js
function* genNumbers() {
  yield* [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

function* genLetters() {
  yield* ["A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D"];
}

function* dedupe(gen) {
  const done = new Set();
  for (const v of gen) {
    if (done.has(v)) continue;
    yield v;
    done.add(v);
  }
}

function* genAll() {
  yield* genNumbers(); 
  yield* genLetters();
}

for (const g of dedupe(genAll())) console.log(g);
```

Comment: `dedupe` works for one generator at a time. However, it's trivial to convert two iterables into one with `function* concat(iterable1, iterable2) { yield* iterable1; yield* iterable2; }` which means `dedupe` can be used over multiple things like so `dedupe(concat([1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 4, 5]))` and would give unique values from both sources total, thus: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: @VLAZ  Yeah, my initial edit had a variant that took an array of generators,.  But then thought it was then moving away from the original question and didn't want to confuse things.  I think generators are one of the features that seems to be missed by a lot of dev's, the async generators are really handy too.

Answer (score 2):

You need two common iterator idioms: `chain` that combines multiple iterators sequentially and `uniq` which returns only unique values from an iterator:

```js
function* genNumbers() {
    yield* [1, 'A', 2, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

function* genLetters() {
    yield* ["A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D"];
}

function* chain(...iters) {
    for (let it of iters)
        yield *it
}

function* uniq(it) {
    const done = new Set();

    for (let x of it) {
        if (!done.has(x)) {
            yield x;
            done.add(x);
        }
    }
}


unqiues = uniq(chain(genNumbers(), genLetters()))
console.log(...unqiues);
```

This assumes you want to uniquify both iterators as a whole, if you want each to be handled separately, it should be the other way around:

```
 chain(uniq(first), uniq(second))
```